Determinant of the Jacobian of QR decomposition?
Suppose the notation $J(X\rightarrow Y)$ of transformation from $X$ to $Y$ is defined as
$$
  J(X\rightarrow Y)=\text{abs}\det\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial y_{1}}&\dots&\frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial y_{p}}\\
   \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
   \frac{\partial x_{p}}{\partial y_{1}}&\dots&\frac{\partial x_{p}}{\partial y_{p}}
  \end{pmatrix}.
 $$
I want to calculate the determinant of the Jacobian of a matrix decomposition $X=TH_{1}$ from $X$ to $T, H_{1}$, where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}, T\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}, H_{1}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ with $p\leqslant n$. Here, rank($X$)=$p$, $T$ is a lower triangular matrix, and $H_{1}$ is semi-orthogonal, that is, $H_{1}H_{1}^{\sf T}=I_{p}$.
The book to which I referred is ``Matrix Variate Distributions'' by Gupta. The result is
$$
 J(X\rightarrow T,H_{1}) = \prod_{i=1}^{p}t_{ii}^{n-i}g_{n,p}(H_{1}),
 $$
which is Eq. (1.3.25) in the following figure. Then my question is why $g_{n,p}(H_{1})$ in the green or blue frame can not be calculated as the equation under the red line, that is to say, why $g_{n,p}(H_{1})$ not equals 1 directly? I am very confused. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!
I post some details as follows.

